# Hilt integration crashes application MainActivity_GeneratedInjector

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

Trying to integrate hilt using android Api Documentation but app crashed with following exception. https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.package.application/com.package.application.MainActivity}: 

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.package.application.DaggerAppApplication_HiltComponents_ApplicationC$ActivityRetainedCImpl$ActivityCImpl 
cannot be cast to com.package.application.MainActivity_GeneratedInjector
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved it by adding missing dependency for androidx hilt.

```
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha01'
```

Other dependencies that I have in my gradle file.

```
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha02"
implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28-alpha'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha'
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5"
```

Plus fragment and its activity who are injecting viewmodel using hilt both are annotated as
@AndroidEntryPoint

Comment: I have the exact same issue, but this doesn't solve it for me

Comment: I have some more dependencies that I have updated in my solution.

Comment: A solution is not to just add dependencies until it works, you dont need androidx compiler if you are not using workmanager with hilt.

Comment: Hi VishalPawar I agree with @AndréRamon androidx annotation processor is only required when you use WorkManager as stated in the official android documentation at https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#workmanager.

Although in my case as well adding that dependency worked but It seems to me this is under the hood accidentally using some hack. 

So please update your answer to reflect these findings

Answer (score 39):

What worked for me:

1. Removed the `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotation from the activity.
2. Ran the code and of course, it failed.
3. Had a fragment inside the activity. So, I deleted the fragment code as well.
4. Ran the code, it failed.
5. Added the `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotation to the activity again.
6. Ran the code. It ran and the error disappeared.

Comment: Hi guys, same problem here when trying to use Hilt, anyone available to help?

I tried all the solutions but without success

Answer (score 24):

For me, as a dependency declaration inside my **app** *build.gradle*, i had to use **api** instead of **implementation**:

**api project(':features:feedModule')**

Learn more here: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2064

**Update**:
Dagger team released classpath aggregation feature which can resolve this issue. You can learn more here:
https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup#classpath-aggregation

Basically, in your app module **build.gradle**, you need to add:

```
hilt {
    enableExperimentalClasspathAggregation = true
}
```

If your Android Gradle plugin version used in the project is less than 7.0, make sure to also add this to you build.gradle file:

```
android {
    ...
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
```

Answer (score 16):

In my case, I was getting a similar `ClassCastException` because the module where my `@HiltAndroidApp` app class was didn't have access to the module where my `@AndroidEntryPoint` activity was. Moving my App class to the app module (that has access to all the other Gradle modules) solved the problem.

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#hilt-modules):

> Because Hilt's code generation needs access to all of the Gradle modules that use Hilt, the Gradle module that compiles your Application class also needs to have all of your Hilt modules and constructor-injected classes in its transitive dependencies.

Comment: Thanks. I had the following structure. Module A -> Module B -> Module C. I had to add a deps to Module C from Module A since A contains the Application

Answer (score 6):

I spent a couple of hours fixing this exact issue but solved it by doing Invalidate cache/restart + Rebuilding of all modules.

This is related to this issue from Hilt:
[Hilt: More meaningful error messages](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1967)

Comment: Same for me...Learning Hilt 1 day wasted trying to figure out what I did incorrectly and this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Dagger sometimes doesn't work well, even if the code is correct.

One possible solution is to rename the class to something else("Class2"), rerun the app, and check if it works. If it works, rename the class back to its original.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and here are the steps I followed:

1. appModule starts with internal
   [image]
2. In your app level build.gradle inside android section add the following line:

   ```
      enableExperimentalClasspathAggregation = true
   }
   ```
3. My dependencies are in this order:

   ````
   classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.40.5"

       app-level build.gradle: 
        top plugin section

    plugin{
     ...........
     id 'kotlin-kapt'
     id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    }

        dependencies section
        //dagger-hilt
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.40.5'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.40.5'```
   ````

Answer (score 0):

For me it was that I forgot to add `@AndroidEntryPoint` to a parent activity that was calling a second activity and this one calling the fragment. Obviously everyone of them need to have an `@AndroidEntryPoint`

Comment: Happened again, this time was that I forgot to add hilt dependency for that specific module.

Answer (score 0):

It is really silly solution but just comment out the injection annotation and injected fields, run the app then uncomment them and run again

Answer (score 0):

It's also happened to me when I'm importing an .aar with "implementation".
(an .aar which includes hilt)

Like [Sher Sanginov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66806692/18163120) said instead of using "api" who increase compilation time, you can add the following lines in your build.gradle(app)

```
hilt {
    enableAggregatingTask = true
}
```

[`enableExperimentalClasspathAggregation`](https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup#classpath-aggregation) is now deprecated,

see https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup#aggregating-task

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same java.lang.ClassCastException after adding Hilt.
Steps to fix the problem:

```
1. Build -> Clean Project
2. Build -> Rebuild Project
```

Also kapt doesn't work any more. Just add one plugin:

```
id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
```

Then, add Hilt dependencies:

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.38.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Steps need to perform:**

- Remove .gradle file in app's directory
- Invalidate cache and restart android studio

Hopefully it will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete you app's build folder as well as delete the gradle build cache on your system.

```
rm -rf app/build

rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches/build-cache-1
```

Deleting just the build cache is better than removing all the Android Studio cache.

Answer (score 0):

In my case file does not contain the package, so hilt is not able to map the file and generate it in the generated folder. For that reason, `hilt` is not able to resolve the file.

I added the `package in the fragment`, and it resolve my issue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was setting the navGraph twice, what caused the cast error:

Once in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
        tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/navigation_app_graph" />
    </activity>
```

And once in the activity_main.xml:

```
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_app_graph"
        tools:ignore="UnusedIds"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_mosaic" />
```

The nav-graph attribute inside the 'activity' tag is defining the navigation graph for the MainActivity activity. This is where you should configure the navigation graph for this activity.

You can remove the other definition, which is inside <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>:

```
app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_app_graph"
```

After all, the navigation graph has already been defined for the main activity, and you don't need to define it again inside the FragmentContainerView.

Answer (score -1):

This is solved by invalidate cache and restart

Comment: **This IS NOT THE CORRECT ANSWER**